# OpenRefine undefined/language error

Tags: undefined, openrefine

New OpenRefine install: I see "Extensions: Undefined", related to the Freebase extension no longer working, plus other texts don't appear when creating the project.

I read somewhere there is a workaround, by setting the language to English (or Italian) on the language settings in the main screen. But I can't find that language settings panel/selection.

Where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Language settings are on the left hand side of the screen shown when OpenRefine opens in your browser - illustrated in this screenshot

[image: Screenshot highlighting Language Settings in OpenRefine]